# In making jsp page in ecllipse, getParameter("textfield1") returns null, where textfield1 is a textbox

Tags: jsp

declaration of textfield1

```
<td nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield1"/></td>
```

trying to return the value entered in textfield1 in name:

```
String name=request.getParameter("textfield1");
```

but by printing the value of name it outputs null, even when the textbox contains string.

Comment: Are you sending any other parameters and this is the only one that's not getting set?  Think we'll need to see the HTML where you're submitting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can happen if the input field is not in the same `<form>` as the submit button. Make sure that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

you must put the

```
<form action="do.jsp" method="post">

<td nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield1"/></td>

</form>
```

do.jsp

```
...
String name=request.getParameter("textfield1");
...
```